# Removing redundant Nodes from the relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is a sample of the data

```
CaseID,name,child,parent
1,register request,examine thoroughly, null
1,examine thoroughly,register request,check ticket
1,check ticket,examine thoroughly,decide
1,decide,check ticket,reject request
1,reject request,decide, null
6,register request,null,examine casually
6,examine casually,register request,check ticket
6,check ticket,examine casually,decide
6,decide,check ticket,pay compensation
6,pay compensation,Mike,200,decide, null
```

Basically, I would like to group by [name] and get all activities with their [children] using Cypher.

Having null in either parent or child means it doesn't have such link.

The following query creates a caretsian product and it makes it very big, while I want to distinct the Activities and get their respective successor.

```
MATCH (p:Activity),(c:Activity)
WHERE p.child=c.name AND c.child <> p.name
CREATE (p)-[r:PRODUCES]->(c)
RETURN collect(r)
```

But unfortunately it produces a cartesian product between all records and it makes the relationship very big.

So, I want just the distinct activities (unique activities) with their respective successors.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create the relationships at import time.

First trick is to remove the extraneous spaces in the header name for easier import, i.e.:

```
CaseID, name, child, parent
```

should become:

```
CaseID,name,child,parent
```

To make sure the subsequent `MERGE` statements can run fast:

```
CREATE INDEX FOR (a:Activity) ON (a.name)
```

Then the import can become (tailor the `dbms.directories.import` and `dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls` settings to your needs):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/import.csv" AS row
MERGE (child:Activity {name: trim(row.child)})
MERGE (parent:Activity {name: trim(row.parent)})
MERGE (parent)-[:PRODUCES]->(child)
```

However, the way the import is written, it will handle the `null` entries as the string `"null"`. To keep things simple, you can just run an extra query *at the end* just to remove that node and its relationships:

```
MATCH (a:Activity {name: "null"}) DETACH DELETE a
```

The data should now be like you want it.

Comment: Well, that actually made it even worse. It actually generated ~600 relationships!

Comment: I tried these queries on the sample dataset you gave on an empty database, ran the query several times, there are no duplicate relationships (which is the whole point of these MERGE statements).
Did you execute the last query as well?